# How to observe an element inside selector using Microsofts API In Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I wan to observe an SVG element inside child selector to trigger a JavaScript function in parent page.

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
const myElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.chart-svg');
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
      entries.forEach((entry) => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          createChart();
          observer.unobserve(myElement);
        }
      });
    });
    observer.observe(myElement);

    createChart(){
    //code....
    }

</script>
```

specified element class .chart-svg is inside child component.
`<app-root></app-root>`

**Error i am getting is:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement')
at (index):19:39**

Can anyone help How can I observe an element inside child component?
FYI: index.html is not an component. Just an html page.